# During zpool scrub, does estimated completion time have a bug shows 0.01% at 10%?

Tags: zfs

I have a raidz2 on a quad of 250G drives in a USB enclosure on linux. Purely for backups. In fact I'm aware at least one drive has issues so it's a fun experiment. Naturally, it has started to hiccup - the drive parks and re-powers the spindle then it's back. Always I can repair/clear the write errors, but while scrub is running on the 673 GB volume, I see 0.01% just now 10% the way through I believe now this is a bug as it is out by exactly factor x100. I guess I could file this in the tracker.

```
scan: scrub in progress since Fri Apr 15 19:53:20 2022
90.1G scanned at 88.7M/s, 59.9M issued at 58.9K/s, 421G total
7.50K repaired, 0.01% done, no estimated completion time

NAME       USED  AVAIL     REFER  MOUNTPOINT
scratchy   318G   355G      318G  /mnt/scratchy
```

Comment: It looks correct to me.  59.9M / 421G is approximately .01%.

Answer (score 0):

I think I answered the question when I noticed it get to 90 GB of processing. 10% != 0.1% = yes there is a bug in zpool status.